# Is there any point in implementing TDD when the project is finished?

Tags: c#, tdd

The project I have been working on is almost finished, I never got the chance to learn TDD before the project started, is there any point in setting up tests now the the project is almost complete? Of course, there will be many add ons and more changes every week, so it's not completely finished.

Thanks

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for Programmers.SE

Answer (score 10):

You could add your unit tests at the end and they will be useful but that's not TDD.

TDD is Test Driven Development, this means that your tests guide the development process. They're not only to check that your logic doesn't fail, but also to help you designing better code and that's why they need to be created first.

Answer (score 1):

It is never too late to set things right.

Comment: That's a nice sound bite but it's not really true. There's absolutely no point in spending time and money when the product has shipped and there is no funding or expectation of support. Academically speaking, there's value, but in commercial situations, that value diminishes greatly.

Comment: My response was too short. TDD can be used for the development of the "many add ons and more changes every week" and by definition, TDD can't be done on existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One of the advantages of having unit tests is so you can tell when something that used to work breaks due to unrelated code changes.

I've been through this before, and when you're adding unit tests to an already (seemingly) finished project, it seems like a meaningless exercise, but it is not:

1. We discovered a lot of small defects this way. Defects that would have otherwise gone undetected until later, and probably would pop up in production
2. The project seemed finished at the time, but then went on for another 6 months, with changes requested by customers, and unit tests turned out to be pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario I would suggest implementing tests in areas of code that match one of the following conditions:

- They're *critical* to the operation of the program
- Nobody will notice immediately if they break

The latter is particularly important. Nothing worse than finding out 5 months after something has broken where the system has been somehow limping on without it. Some things need to be made more visible and tests can be a good way of doing that.

Obviously its best to put tests everywhere but that might be both against the needs of your scheduling and politically difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It is always worth having tests. You may implement some tests now and find that you have some major bugs in your code. Even if you only do some basic tests for now and then build them up gradually. Then with any new bits use the TDD.

Its also useful for spotting if any changes that you make break other sections of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will now have the difficult task of trying to retro fit tests into legacy code.  There are many articles online and many ways to achieve it (GoldenMaster, it's great for WCF-y stuff).  I would say if you are expected to support the software/add features it is worth investing in implementing at least some tests (especially around the critical areas).